# Error put my var in string parameter with ${} reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Error: paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain . # $ or

but my code is :

```
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const emailRef = rootRef.child(`${email}`).set({
  firstName,
  lastName
}).catch(err => {
  setErrors(prev => ([...prev, err.message]))
})
```

Help please :)

Answer (score 0):

What happened if you change?

```
const emailRef = rootRef.child(`${email}`).set({
```

to

```
const emailRef = rootRef.child(email).set({
```

Comment: because type is any, and so it writes in my DB email the name of the var and not are contained

Comment: Okay, so try to change the ``${email}`` to `'email'`

Comment: ok sorry, when I just put the var like that, it made the error and when I do 'email' it writes email to my db, but not its content

Comment: What is the content of your email var? is it a leagel string for sure?

Comment: email of user, yes it is sure because I also recover it to create an account there it is just to store information of the user